# Table footnote of Latex table environment in r markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

As you can see the problem in table notes in the figure below. I generated the latex code from `stargazer` function and manually adjusted it to meet my requirement. The table note troubled me however. how do I format the `note` to be the same height with the note contexts.

[image]

My latex code looks like below

```
\begin{table}[h] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
  \caption{Regression results} 
  \label{results} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
\hline\\[-1.8ex]
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{A. Daily Max 8-hour Ozone Concentration} \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 TreatedPost & 0.034$^{***}$ & 0.006 & $-$0.063$^{***}$ & $-$0.098$^{***}$ & $-$0.105$^{***}$ \\ 
  & 0.012 & (0.007) & (0.017) & (0.023) & (0.023) \\ 
  & & & & & \\[-1.8ex]
\hline\\[-1.8ex]
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{B. Daily PM2.5} \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 TreatedPost & $-$0.245$^{***}$ & $-$0.374$^{***}$ & $-$0.505$^{***}$ & 0.203$^{***}$ & 0.230$^{**}$ \\ 
  & 0.051 & (0.025) & (0.053) & (0.067) & (0.080) \\ 
  & & & & & \\[-1.8ex] 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
County fixed &  & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Time fixed &  &  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
County-specific trend &  &  &  & Yes & Yes \\
Climate control &  &  &  &  & Yes \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\hline \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[Note:] In the table, column (1)-(5) represent different models. Column (1) refers to a simple linear model; Column(2) indicates a panel data regression with county-fixed effect; Column(3) represents a panel data model with county- and time-fixed effect; Column (4) introduces county-specific time trend; Column (5) furture includes climate control variables. For panel data models, errors are clustered at county level. {$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Obligatory note that you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/) package. Use ‘texreg’ instead, or literally *anything* else.

Comment: @KonradRudolph With all respect, I think `stargazer` is pretty handy....The problem is not associated with `stargazer`, instead, I think it's the `threeparttable` function we should edit on.